# WebBrowser control doesn't work on the second time in C#

Tags: c#, .net, web, controls

I have a project that interact with the web site through an application.

The idea is, when I click into a specific web element, a second form will appear. it contains two text-boxes, after input the values and press Enter, it will paste the pallet value to the pallet ID on the web page and press the "+" button and submit the web page. it worked on the first time. However, after the webpage is submitted. I can't do the same things again, although I close the second form and open it again by clicking on that web element.

When debugging, the system did realize the Enter press, and do all the code in it including paste the value into the pallet ID and click the "+" button. However, it just works on the first time, after the the web submitted it doesn't work anymore

I don't know why? maybe I were wrong some where, I don't have much experience in programming C#.

this is the image of it

http://i182.photobucket.com/albums/x38/DNK90/app_zpsd55a4065.jpg

after the web page is submit, the second form still there, so I think it could the problem.

here is my code:

Form 1: I just post the part that display the form 2 and get element from the web

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        pallet_element = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("pallet_id");
        weighing_element = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("weighing_auto");
        add_new_element = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("btnNewWNR");
        no_Of_WNR = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("noOfWNR");

        if (no_Of_WNR != null)
        {
            // number of row
            int no = Convert.ToInt32(no_Of_WNR.GetAttribute("value"));
            // button that saves a row
            //save_element = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("btnSaveWNR" + no);
            // gross weight of a row
            gross_element = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("wnr_gross_weight_" + no);
        }

        if (pallet_element != null && weighing_element != null && add_new_element != null && gross_element != null)
        {
            frm2 = new Form2(pallet_element, weighing_element, add_new_element, gross_element);

            pallet_element.Click += new HtmlElementEventHandler(OpenWeigh);
        }            
    }

    public void OpenWeigh(object sender, HtmlElementEventArgs e)
    {            
        // setting the COM port connection
        frm2.SettingRS232(count);
        count++;
        frm2.ShowDialog();            
    }
```

Form 2:

```
private void txtPallet_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {           
        if (e.KeyChar == '\r')
        {
            if (this.pallet_element != null && this.weighing_element != null && add_new_element != null)
            {                    
                // althought the flow comming and get through of below rows
                // but nothing happened on the web after the first time run successfully

                // set value in the txtPallet into pallet_id
                this.pallet_element.InnerText = txtPallet.Text;
                this.weighing_element.InnerText = txtWeight.Text;
                add_new_element.InvokeMember("click");
                this.gross_element.InnerText = txtWeight.Text;                   
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this a state problem related to the fact that u did "something" with the first post back. Are you incrementing a counter or "something" to shift you to a new target? It would seem like a logical design could be that you shouldn't be able to do the same thing twice (depending on business rules) to the same data? Are you acting on the same data or different data in the second post back? Pls also define what you mean by second time not working? Does the data get sent off but nothing happens or does the send not happen. Is there even a "+" button available for a given row after you post back?

Comment: I think the answer might well lie in the HTML. Id compare the 2 documents after postback and make sure you're properly targeting the correct elements.

Comment: actually, the pallet ID and the "+" button that you see in the image is static, no matter I add any row to the web page. I just have to paste the value to the pallet Id and press the "+" button automatically, the rest is the web job (javascript)

Comment: After you submit a pallet id does that row still have a text box for the pallet id or does it change to a label?

Comment: Also when you say "after the web page is submit, the second form still there, so I think it could the problem." - why is it still there? Why cant you do a this.Close() on the Form2? Seems like an easy thing to rule out. If you're not closing it then you're also not disposing it so there could be an open / blocking connection within it if thats the case.

Comment: Without knowing the nature of your app it's hard to say but typically you would be better off separating UI from business logic. If frm2 is full of connection logic then you'd be better of refactoring out into a separate class. This frm2.SettingRS232(count); looks alot like your're storing connections etc in UI components which is probably not good / harder to test. Really need to see the full Form2 code.

Comment: I keep the form2 open because I want it continuously when the data that is sent from com port post to the weight and enter the value to pallet ID, enter is pressed then a new row is added. it's my boss requirement :)                                                     The rest of form2 is just a constructor that set the value following in form1 and the settingRS232(), it's the function that connect to the COM port that read data and post it on the weight textbox.      Anyway, I've fixed that by getting the data and paste it straight into the web form, the enter will be execute through javascri